# Fragment's button listener on activity - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have tabbed activity using fragments and in one of them i have a button, but i can only use in the fragment itself but now, I want to use it in my MainActivity?

is there a way to have a Fragment's button listener on activity?

Comment: Please post relevant code if you really want someone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

there are two methods

1. You can write a Button click event callback in the fragment
2. You can write in activity

   ```
     ((Button)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(/*frgment                     id*/).getView().findViewById(R.id.one_nextpager)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
            }
          });
   ```